# Urgent - iPhone disabled, rescue data

Tags: iphone, recovery, data-recovery, ios

I have the iPhone 6s of my grandma here.  She asked me if I could recover the photos she has made with her iPhone after it disabled itself for some reason.

I have already updated it multiple times over the recovery mode with iTunes. If anybody has any idea on how I could solve this quickly, I would be forever thankful. I believe my mother would love to have some of these pictures as well.

Comment: Do you have a Mac computer to connect it to?

Comment: It is most likely you will need professional help.  Try: drivesavers.com

Comment: Your question is short on detail. 'Disabled itself' how? What is the symptom… black screen, password request, timeout until next attempt…? Also 'updated it with iTunes'... again, what happened, what did you see? Additionally - is the phone backed up to a Mac or PC, or iCloud?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no backup and it says, that this device is disabled and I should connect it with iTunes. If I normally connect it it is not recognized, only over recocery mode. There I either update it, or restore it and loose everything on it, which is not an option. I have a Mac with yosemite, windows 10 and Linux Mint, so all options there is.

Comment: Thanks for the hint historystamp, but it seems that I need to check for an alternative that also serves Germany, since this one seems to operate only in the US and Australia.

Comment: Does your grandma have an iCloud account? Was the phone logged into an iCloud account before it was disabled? Did you check to see if the photos are in iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

If you've restored the phone once, the data is no longer on the device.

You (your grandma) would have either needed a backup via iTunes on their computer, or backups being made via iCloud.

If you plugged the phone into her computer and there weren't restores available, and the iPhone setup phase doesn't say it can restore from iCloud, there's no backups to restore.

However, phone backups and service data are two different things. There is a *change* that if you set up the phone and log her back into her Apple ID, her "live account data" (service data) would come back if they were being stored in iCloud via iCloud Photos.

Have you gone all the way through the restore process and Apple ID login on her phone?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to recover any contents off an iPhone that has been disabled. The contents is resting in an encrypted state on the iPhone and is only decrypted by a key which is constructed by several parts, one of which is the lock code used when unlocking an iPhone.
I will assume there was a lock code in use since for an iPhone to become permanently disabled I think the wrong lock code needs to be entered 10 times.

When you get the "iPhone is disabled, connect to iTunes" message on your iPhone, the decryption key has been permanently discarded and the same unique key can not be reconstructed by anybody, as the key is constructed the first time you set up the iPhone by, amongst other things, the random input from the microphone at the time.